# What purpose does MyClass.class.getName() serve?

Tags: java

I'm reviewing code that features this construction.  `MyClass` is the name of a class.  Why would a someone use

```
String name = MyClass.class.getName();
```

instead of

```
String name = "MyClass";
```

given that the class name is already identified in the former?  Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: These two lines of code don't do the same thing. Unless the class is in the default package (which is a bad, bad practice). The first one keeps doing the right thing if you rename or move the class. The second doesn't.

Comment: In some code, a Class object may represent one of many different classes. The `getName()` method allows you to get the name of the specific class represented.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the class is later renamed, then the `MyClass.class.getName()` reference will need to be checked and fixed up in order to compile (or will be fixed up automatically by the IDE). The string will not, which means it will compile correctly, but not actually work correctly, which is worse because it hides the problem.

Referring to the class name this way is an application of the [Don't Repeat Yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) principle.

Answer (score 7):

If you accidentally spell the first one `MyClas.class.getName()`, it won't compile. The second one will.

Also, as JB Nizet points out, `getName` includes the full package hierarchy in the name. For example, if `MyClass` is under the `com.piotrchernin` package, `MyClass.class.getName()` will be `"com.piotrchernin.MyClass"`, not `"MyClass"`.

Comment: @YassinHajaj: I'm not sure what you're trying to say there. Were you thinking of `getSimpleName()`?

Comment: [Indeed, my bad sorry](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Class.java#Class.getSimpleName%28%29)

Comment: Thank you!  I have to note that of all the documentation, tutorials, and SO questions I've reviewed to learn about this, not one (even the official docs) bothered to state clearly that getName() returns the full hierarchy of the class.

Comment: @PiotrChernin: On one hand, the `getName` docs don't directly state it. On the other hand, they do give the example that `String.class.getName()` returns `"java.lang.String"`, which includes the package hierarchy, and if you follow the JLS references, you can find the sections on [binary name](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-13.html#jls-13.1) and [canonical name](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.7).

Answer (score 2):

The method `getName()`:

- Works for code that has a Class object, but does not know the actual class.
- Continues to work after the class has been renamed.
- Works on Class objects representing arrays.

**Code that does not know the class**

As you note, one way to obtain a Class object is `MyClass.class`. However, it is not the only way. You can also call the method `getClass()` on an object of a class -- even in code that's referring to the object via an interface or superclass type. And some code receives a Class object from a caller.

As an example of the former, consider the following class hierarchy and factory method:

```
public interface IFoo { }
public class AlphaFoo implements IFoo {}
public class BetaFoo implements IFoo {}
public FooFactory {
  public static IFoo makeFoo() { ... }
}
```

The caller of the factory does not know what kind of IFoo will be returned. If you wanted to debug-print the actual class received from the factory, you could do this:

```
IFoo foo = FooFactory.makeFoo();
System.out.println( foo.getClass().getName() );
```

**Refactoring**

As an example of resilience to refactoring, consider this creation of a standard Java logger:

```
public class Bar {
   private static final Logger s_logger = Logger.getLogger(
     Bar.class.getName() );
   ...
}
```

If I rename the class using my IDE's refactoring tools, the logger name will update automatically.

**Arrays**

You can call `getName()` on a Class object representing an array.

```
String[] strs = new String[] { "alpha", "beta", "gamma" };
System.out.println( strs.getClass().getName() );
```

The output is:

```
[Ljava.lang.String;
```

Now, you might ask how this is useful. This syntax turns out to be how array arguments are expressed in calls to the JNI method `GetMethodID()`, which is necessary to call Java methods from C/C++.